# Sql Query error in asp.net using C# Application

Tags: c#, sql

i have simply tried to show the details  by data grid make use of this query

```
select 
P.Sitename as Site
,P.Vendorname as Vendor
,P.POno,PS.Itemcode as ItemCode
,sum(PS.Quantity) as Qty
,sum(PS.Basic) as Basic
,Sum(PS.DiscountAmt) as [Disc Amt]
,sum(PS.PFAmt) as [PF Amt]
,sum(PS.EDAmt) as [ED Amt]
,sum(PS.VATCSTAmt) as [VATCST Amt]
,sum(PS.Netamt) as Total
,I.Itemname as Itemname
,I.UOM as UOM  
from tbl_Itemmaster I, tbl_Purchaseorder_sub PS,tbl_Purchaseorder P 
where P.POdate between '8/30/2012' and '8/31/2012' 
and PS.status in (4,5) 
and I.Itemidentify=Ps.ITemcode 
and PS.pono=p.POno 
group by PS.Itemcode,P.Sitename,P.Vendorname,I.Itemname,I.UOM   
order by Site,Vendor,ItemCode
```

but, i have got the error while executing this, which is,

```
"Column 'tbl_Purchaseorder.POno' is invalid in the select list because 
it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."
```

Please can anyone tell me how can i correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add POno to the GROUP BY Cluase

Something like

```
select  P.Sitename as Site,
        P.Vendorname as Vendor,
        P.POno,
        PS.Itemcode as ItemCode,
        sum(PS.Quantity) as Qty,
        sum(PS.Basic) as Basic,
        Sum(PS.DiscountAmt) as [Disc Amt],
        sum(PS.PFAmt) as [PF Amt],
        sum(PS.EDAmt) as [ED Amt],
        sum(PS.VATCSTAmt) as [VATCST Amt],
        sum(PS.Netamt) as Total ,
        I.Itemname as Itemname,
        I.UOM as UOM  
from    tbl_Itemmaster I, 
        tbl_Purchaseorder_sub PS,
        tbl_Purchaseorder P 
where   P.POdate between '8/30/2012' 
and     '8/31/2012' 
and     PS.status in (4,5) 
and     I.Itemidentify=Ps.ITemcode 
and     PS.pono=p.POno 
group by    PS.Itemcode,
            P.Sitename,
            P.Vendorname,
            I.Itemname,
            I.UOM,
            P.POno <-- You need to add this to your query
order by    Site,
            Vendor,
            ItemCode
```

Comment: Please select this as your answer, if it answered your question